# `VirtualAllocEx` returns same address when specifying different start addresses?

Tags: c++, winapi, virtualalloc

I'm trying to bring calc.exe to show a messagebox, but calc.exe always crashes as soon as I execute my program. So I tried to inject the code to my own process in order to see debugging messages. Doing so gives me the exception "Access violation at... Cannot execute..." pointing to `pData->msg`. Then I found out that `pThread` and `pData` get the same address. How is this possible? I actually set `lpAddress` of `VirtualAllocEx` to `pPage` and `pPage + 128` to not get the same start address.

```cpp
// Allocate page
void *pPage = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 256, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

// Commit memory for thread procedure
void *pThread = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, pPage, 128, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

// Commit memory for thread data
void *pData = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, (void*)((long long)pPage + 128), 128, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

// WriteProcessMemory, do stuff

// Release memory
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pPage, 256, MEM_RELEASE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VirtualAllocEx allocates memory with portions divisible memory page size which is 4096 byte.

> dwSize [in]
>   The size of the region, in bytes. If the lpAddress parameter is NULL, this value is rounded up to the next page boundary. Otherwise, the allocated pages include all pages containing one or more bytes in the range from lpAddress to lpAddress+dwSize. This means that a 2-byte range straddling a page boundary causes both pages to be included in the allocated region.
>
> lpAddress [in, optional]
>   The pointer that specifies a desired starting address for the region of pages that you want to allocate.
>   If you are reserving memory, the function rounds this address down to the nearest multiple of the allocation granularity.

Try to use Heap function (HeapAlloc, HeapFree, HeapCreate).

Or you can do something like this:

```
// Allocate page
void *pPage = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, 256, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

// Commit memory for thread data
void *pData = (char*)pPage + 128;

// WriteProcessMemory, do stuff

// Release memory
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pPage, 256, MEM_RELEASE);
```

Comment: So instead, I just need to offset the write address of the thread data and not the memory allocation?

Comment: In fact you should know that dwSize == 256 means that was allocated a 4096 bytes.